# My local server can't find bower files when I run my application

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, polymer, bower

i have to run an application from a local repo (called exoplanet-explorer). I installed Node.js and Git, and I followed these steps:

in the command line of Git Bash:

```
  git clone https://github.com/udacity/exoplanet.explorer.git
  cd exoplanet-explorer
  npm install -g gulp bower
  npm install && bower install
  gulp serve
```

When I run gulp serve, the app page opens but it's blank. In the console this list of errors appears:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) webcomponents-lite.js:1 

(index):1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:5000/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

:5000/bower_components/iron-flex-layout/classes/iron-flex-layout.html:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   

:5000/bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

:5000/bower_components/iron-selector/iron-selector.html:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

:5000/bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

:5000/bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

:5000/bower_components/paper-scroll-header-panel/paper-scroll-header-panel.html:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

:5000/bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles-classes.html:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

:5000/bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

[Deprecation] Styling master document from stylesheets defined in HTML Imports is deprecated, and is planned to be removed in M67, around May 2018. Please refer to  for possible migration paths.

page.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

(index):1 Refused to execute script from 

'http://localhost:5000/bower_components/page/page.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

:5000/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

planet-thumb.html:78 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
at planet-thumb.html:78
at planet-thumb.html:100

scale-visualizer.html:68 Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
at scale-visualizer.html:68
at scale-visualizer.html:189
```

What can I do?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in macOS High Sierra with Node 10. Might be a `browser-sync` issue (with `git bash`?) since that's the lib that maps your `bower_components` route. Does this only occur in `git bash`? Have you tried this in a different terminal program? What is your version of Node?

Comment: My Node version is 8.11.1. I tried from windows prompt and it's the same. Actually those bower files really don't exist in the exoplanet-explorer directory, that's why I think it's a bower installation issue

Comment: What's the error when you try to install them?

Comment: It completes the install, doesn't give errors during installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on the same project and I had the exact same issues, using  Windows 10 Home, git version 2.15.1.windows.2 and node v8.11.3, npm v6.1.0, bower v1.8.4, gulp v3.9.1. I looked to where the bower_components folder is supposed to be located and there is absolutely nothing there. I also opened bash as administrator to install.

- [screenshot of my errors when I first load the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd7cx.png)
- [screenshot of my errors when I refresh the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GKch.png)

If you are having these errors, bower is NOT installing the polymer-starter-kit properly for whatever reason or you forgot/failed to install it yourself. I actually watched my installs fail, as over and over i would install, type "***bower list***" and it would tell me the polymer files in the starter kit that I needed, were still not installed - but I just saw the files install.

- [bower list shows the files still NOT being saved to the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEx2S.jpg)

So I had to do a "***bower install -f polymer-starter-kit***" after i did this and then installed gulp and typed gulp serve everything worked perfectly. Hope this helps someone else - I just spent over 16 hours yesterday and 5 today trying to figure this out. **NOTE:** you might want to do a "*bower cache clean*" first.

- [bower install -f polymer-starter-kit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGa4t.jpg)
- [Errors resolved!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoVfC.jpg)